# Node.js callback not working

Tags: node.js, callback

I have the following two Node.js files:

```
//test.js
var hash=require('./hash');
var sys=require('sys');

hash.hash("asdf",function(param){
        sys.puts(param);
});
```

and

```
//hash.js:
var exec=require('child_process').exec;
var sys=require('sys');

exports.hash=function(data,callback){
        exec("./a.out "+data,function callback(error,stdout,stderr){
                callback(stdout);
        });
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make stdout available in test.js

Trouble is, when I run `node test.js`, I get the following error:

```
eamorr@Compaq6000:~/Desktop/simple-hash$ node test.js 

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Anyone got any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

---

Edit: solution: rename the inner "callback" to "callback2" or something else... Thanks to Idan K for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `exec` you are naming what should be an anonymous function, `callback`. This has the same name as the second argument to `hash`, hence the recursion.

Comment: yes, I just realised this! Thank you so much for pointing that out. *bangs head off desk*

Comment: @Eamorr: there's actually no need to give it a name, but changing the name will fix it too.